# Server 2012 User logins log

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, logging, audit

As part of a technical team at an institution I am needing a way to view users logging onto computers in realtime

What I would like to know is if I can have an auto updating program/script that will let me know when a user logs in and where and the timestamp.

This way I can just slap it on a monitor and it will update like a log fild telling me when AD users log onto a pc around the institution

Any help would be greatly appreciated